# App crashes on lock/sleep screen - NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Using a device for testing - Whenever I lock the screen (or sleeps after 1 min idle), the app crashes and the `logcat` shows a `NullPointerException` always on an `imageView.setOnClickListener` in the `onResume()` method.

Here's the small part of the code where I get the exception :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.critical_items_list);

    // instantiate member variables

    mExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mItems_P1 = mExtras.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_ITEMS_P1);
    mItems_P2 = mExtras.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_ITEMS_P2);
    mItems_Engine = mExtras.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_ITEMS_ENGINE); 
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ImageView imageAddToMultiple = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_add_to_multiple);

    //This is where the I get the NullPointer
    imageAddToMultiple.setOnClickListener(listenerAddToMultipleItems); 

    refreshLists();
    ListView listP1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_p1);
    ListView listP2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_p2);
    ListView listEngine = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_engine);

    listP1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mList_P1));
    listP2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mList_P2));
    listEngine.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mList_Engine));
}
```

The imageView itself lies in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_bar_height"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/plant_1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/plant_2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_add_to_multiple"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_bar_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_bar_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_add_to_multiple_items"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/engine"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_p1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/green" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_p2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/green" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_engine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no clue why I'm getting this `NullPointer`.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {nmw.nss/nmw.nss.CriticalList}: java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2820)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2242)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)     Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   nmw.nss.CriticalList.onResume(CriticalList.java:93)
>
> at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4620)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804)
>     ... 12 more

Thanks.

EDIT : I've added the complete activity(sort of), the `xml`, and the `logcat`.
Do I need to override any of `Activity` methods, perhaps the `onStop` or `onPause` to make this work?

Comment: but where you have declared listview ?

Comment: @gtumca-MAC listview is of no concern, that is just part of my activity. To confirm it, I removed the imageView and its listener code entirely, and it was working perfectly. So definitely findViewById is returning null

Answer (score 4):

Finally found it!
My app is basically designed to run in landscape mode, and in the manifest I've added  -------
android:screenOrientation="landscape".

Well, here's the problem : it doesn't matter in what mode you lock the device, findViewById() always searches the XML in the portrait mode, and in my case, which did not have the ImageView at all. Hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: same prblm here for my app can you tell me what will be the solution for this

Comment: Since I never used the portrait mode, it didn't really matter what the layout XML contained, I simply copied all the code from the landscape from the XML, to the portrait

Comment: That's the problem, yes. Here's how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29494115/1760313

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have not called `setContentView()` before, thus `Imageview imageAddToMultiple` is null and when you try to set the listener, it crashes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i've called it in the onCreate method, I tried putting that in the onResume, and it made no difference

Comment: Do you have defined listenerAddToMultipleItems?

Comment: Yes, of course...all it does is set a different kind of adapter for the lists (irrelevant to the question, hence i didn't put it up)